# Where does "Grand Sorcerer" title for Dumbledore come from in canon?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

[Dumbledore Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Albus_Dumbledore) info card says:

> ```
>  Title(s)       ... Grand Sorcerer
> ```

This fact is mentioned, but nowhere is it referenced/cited.

Where in HP canon (books/interviews/pottermore) is the fact sourced from?

Was that on his Chocolate Frog card?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The title was abbreviated** in the book.

It was listed in the letter that Hogwarts sent to Harry regarding his acceptance, in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, *CHAPTER FOUR: The Keeper of the Keys*

> HOGWARTS SCHOOL OF WITCHCRAFT AND WIZARDRY
>
> Headmaster: Albus Dumbledore
>
> (Order of Merlin, First Class, **Grand Sorc.**, Chf. Warlock, Supreme Mugwump, International Confed. of Wizards)
>
> Dear Mr Potter,
>
> We are pleased to inform you that you have a place at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find enclosed a list of all necessary books and equipment....

Comment: You are awesome @DVK

Comment: @AjoKoshy - all credit goes to FireFox and the little friend called "Ctrl-F" :)

Comment: Do you read HP books on web (not locally in ePub, Mobi or PDF format)? Where?

Comment: In HTML format?

Comment: @SachinShekhar I'm assuming DVK went to the wiki site linked within the question, and put "Ctrl-F" to good use there...

Comment: @BMWurm - if you read the Q and A carefully, the site Wiki had no canon references, and book reference is what the answer provides.